# Realm migration is needed exception even though I reset database

Tags: java, android, realm

I am getting a migration is needed exception on my main activity. This is okay as there is a migration needed. However I added the code below beneath `Realm.init(this)` to make the database reset should there be one required. However I am still getting this error.

Any suggestions?

```
// Initialize Realm (just once per application)
Realm.init(this);

RealmConfiguration config = new RealmConfiguration
        .Builder()
        .deleteRealmIfMigrationNeeded()
        .build();
```

I am intending on doing correct migrations in future, but for now just for the database to be reset would work for me.

Comment: is the app crashing before reaching  `.deleteRealmIfMigrationNeeded()` or after?

Comment: I actually can't tell, the log doesn't give me where in the main activity this has happened

Comment: place debug point at realmconfiguration and run app in debug mode. if it crashed without stoping at debug point then your code isn't executing.

Comment: Okay will do ...

Comment: You shouldn't forget `Realm.setDefaultConfiguration(config)`

Comment: Should that not have still worked though?

Comment: If you didn't set this config you built as the default config, then probably not

Comment: Does that work globally though? Or everywhere I call setDefault so I need to add the config?